# Calling inherited method form base class

Tags: php, inheritance

I have an extended class with an overriden method doSomething().
For some reason the inherited class' method never runs only the base one.

```
class cDemoClass {

  public static function getInstance() {
    static $instance = null;

    if ($instance === null)
      $instance = new cDemoClass();
    return $instance;
  } 

  private function __construct() {
  } 

  protected function doSomething() {
    echo 'do something';
  }

  public function call_me() {
    $this->doSomething();
  }
} 

class cDemoClassEx extends cDemoClass {

  protected function doSomething() {
    echo 'do something differently';
  }
}

$baseclass = cDemoClass::getInstance();
$baseclass->call_me();
echo '<br/>';
$extendedclass = cDemoClassEx::getInstance();
$extendedclass->call_me();
```

result:

do something

do something

The second one should be "do something differently" at least that's what I'm expecting.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need using `late static binding` (5.3+). Change in parent method `getInstance` line :

```
$instance = new cDemoClass();
```

to

```
$instance = new static();
```

You will get:

```
do something
do something differently
```

Read more about this feature here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Answer (score 1):

Because `cDemoClassEx::getInstance();` is still returning `new cDemoClass();`. You have to also overwrite the `getInstance()` method:

```
class cDemoClass {

  public static function getInstance() {
    static $instance = null;

    if ($instance === null)
      $instance = new cDemoClass();
    return $instance;
  } 

  private function __construct() {
  } 

  protected function doSomething() {
    echo 'do something';
  }

  public function call_me() {
    $this->doSomething();
  }
} 

class cDemoClassEx extends cDemoClass {
  public static function getInstance() {
    static $instance = null;

    if ($instance === null)
      $instance = new cDemoClassEx();
    return $instance;
  } 

  private function __construct() {
  } 

  protected function doSomething() {
    echo 'do something differently';
  }
}

$baseclass = cDemoClass::getInstance();
$baseclass->call_me();
echo '<br/>';
$extendedclass = cDemoClassEx::getInstance();
$extendedclass->call_me();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override with the cDemoClassEx::getInstance() and change this line

```
$instance = new cDemoClass();
```

into

```
$instance = new cDemoClassEx();
```

You will also need to declare the `cDemoClass::__construct()` as `protected` or simply override it in `cDemoClassEx`.